# Activerecord complex join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem with an activerecord join.

I have an object "user" that follows some items, and an object "content" that has some followable items (brands in this case) associated.

`u` and `c` are my user and my content.

Now I have these two queries:

```
bf = u.follows.where('followable_type = ?', "Brand").map(&:followable_id)

[22, 188, 182, 71, 24, 2]

c.brands.map(&:id)

[2]
```

I need to obtain an array with the values present in both query, so in this case [2].

How can I write a single query?

Something like

```
bf = u.follows.where('followable_type = ?', "Brand").where followable_id are inside c.brands_ids
```

**Update:**

```
brands = author.follows.where('followable_type = ?', "Brand").where(followable_id: content.brands.map(&:id)).map(&:followable).map(&:name).join(', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this query:

```
sql_subquery = u.follows.where(followable_type: 'Brand').select(:followable_id).to_sql
u.follows.where( followable_id: sql_subquery )
```

Also, a good advice, try using complete names for variables. It makes your code more readable, even for you.

Comment: I don't believe you need the `to_sql` part (though there's no harm in leaving it in, of course). If the "subquery" portion returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, it'll resolve as a subquery regardless.

Comment: mmm ... how am I supposed to help you with just "it doesn't work" ? @RobertoPezzali What is the error message ? etc etc ....

Comment: Ah sorry, I found something that works and I updated my question